# Correct usage of microdata itemscopes in combination with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, schema.org, microdata

Because I'm using asp.net MVC the views are rendered in my body using @RenderBody()
My question is: **am I correctly using the schema.org microdata?**

In my example I have the html which is WebSite, it has some meta data in the header for WebSite itemscope. 
Next I set the mainEntityOfPage to WebPage and add header, footer.
Some pages that will apear in the @RenderBody() have an own scope (e.g. ContactPage) and other have just data with some itemscopes of Product or Place.

Is this the correct way of using microdata?

Simplified _Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta property="og:title" content="test">
    <meta itemprop="about" content="test">
</head>
<body itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <div class="myheader" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <div class="...">
             <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarwrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                @*...*@
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()

    <div>
         @* some other stuff*@
    </div>

        <div class="myfooter" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
        @*...*@
        </div>
</body>
```

Simplified Index.cshtml (Home) which is shown in the @RenderBody(), and thus in the WebPage itemscope without any other itemscopes:

```
<div class="...">
@* content *@    
</div>
```

Simplified Contact.cshtml (Home) which is shown in the @RenderBody(), and thus in the WebPage itemscope with other scopes:

```
<div class="banner">
    @* banner stuff *@  
    </div>
    <div class="myMiddleContent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPage">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                @*...*@

                <div class="col-md-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                 @*...*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is what i have now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta property="og:title" content="test">
    <meta itemprop="about" content="test">
    <meta itemprop="headline" content="my fancy pancy site">
    <meta itemprop="cool, things here">
</head>
<body itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPage"> @* or /WebPage *@

    <div class="myheader" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <div class="...">
             <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarwrapper" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                @*...*@
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    @* injected via @RenderBody() *@
    <div class="banner">
    @* banner stuff *@  
    </div>
    <div class="myMiddleContent">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                @* list of products...*@

                <div class="col-md-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                 @*product x...*@
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
                 @* product y...*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div itemprop="contentLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Museum">
        <link itemprop="additionalType" href="http://schema.org/TouristAttraction">
         <meta itemprop="name" content="Foo bar">
         <meta itemprop="sameAs" content="http://www.facebook.com/FooBar">
          <div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
            @*...*@
          </div>
    </div>
    @* end of injected via @RenderBody() *@


    <div>
         @* some other stuff*@
    </div>

    <div class="myfooter" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
        @*...*@
    </div>

    @*website/webpage creator / author / etc... *@    
    <div itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        <meta itemprop="name" content="...">
        @*...*@
    </div>
    <div itemprop="copyrightHolder" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
        @*...*@
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your approach. I suggest running your rendered page through a validator and checking if the result is as expected.

Comment: I used google, yandex, etc.. but one tells you it is not correct, other tells you it is correct. but I don't know if it is because they don't support everything or if it is wrong or...

Comment: Hmm, I guess it depends on the error. I find the google one supports the most items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Index.cshtml has no schema markup within, I'll talk about Contact.cshtml when inserted in _Layout.cshtml. This applies to Index.cshtml except when referring to content in Contact.cshtml.

The schema markup is read as follows:

- WebSite

  - mainEntityOfPage: WebPage
- WPHeader
- SiteNavigationElement
- ContactPage
- Place
- WPFooter

There are a number of problems with the markup, including but not limited to the lack of hierarchical organisation of the items on the page and incorrect schema.org usage. I will discuss your code line by line below:

> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite">
> ```

This markup informs that the HTML on this page is a web *site*. This is fine, but may not be what you intend. Terminology is important with schema markup — perhaps this should be a WebPage instead? I'll come back to this later.

> ```html
> <head prefix="go: http://ogp.me/ns#">
>     <meta property="og:title" content="test">
>     <meta itemprop="about" content="test">
> </head>
> <body itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
> ```

Here you're stating that the WebSite is the mainEntityOfPage: WebPage. This is almost certainly not what you intended. To clarify, you're saying the WebPage (this single page) mainEntity (the main content of this single page) is WebSite (the entire site). I encourage you to check [schema.org/mainEntityOfPage](https://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage) for the specification of this property. Here's what I would do instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta property="og:title" content="test">
    <meta itemprop="about" content="test">
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

Removing the itemprop removes the link from the WebPage to the WebSite and as you're not using any WebSite properties the WebSite schema can be removed.

> ```html
> <div class="myheader" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
>     <div class="...">
>          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarwrapper" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
>             @*...*@
>          </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

These are two completely separate schemas. They are not associated with each other, nor with the WebPage schema. You're missing the itemprop attribute on both these. Both of them should include `itemprop="hasPart"` to define the following hierarchy:

- WebPage

  - hasPart: WPHeader

    - hasPart: SiteNavigationElement

> ```html
> <div class="banner">
>     @* banner stuff *@  
>     </div>
>     <div class="myMiddleContent" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPage">
> ```

This is a bit difficult, because ContactPage is a WebPage, but you're already in the scope of a WebPage and it's not a different page as such. Usually you would link these two with `itemprop="mainEntity"` but the item type is a WebPage, so this is incorrect. mainContentOfPage is for WebPageElement, but again you've defined an entire page.

This is where the WebPage schema should be replaced with ContactPage, but I understand that your ‘drop-in’ to `@RenderBody()` doesn't accommodate this. I guess mainEntity is the best you can do if you can't change the WebPage schema based on which page you're inserting (WebPage is still the most appropriate schema for Index.cshtml). If you *are* able to change the layout page when inserting the contact page, you should change the WebPage to ContactPage, and not use mainEntity. As the schema in the contact page as discussed later applies to the ContactPage schema, you do not need to make any further changes later.

The schema so far, presuming you are unable to change the layout page when inserting the contact page, is the following:

- WebPage

  - hasPart: WPHeader

    - hasPart: SiteNavigationElement
  - mainEntity: ContactPage

> ```html
> <div class="container">
>     <div class="row">
>             @*...*@
>
>             <div class="col-md-6" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
> ```

This Place is completely separate from anything so far — again, an itemprop is missing from this schema. Use contentLocation (or define an Organization/etc to contain the Place). Then, you'll end up with…

- WebPage

  - hasPart: WPHeader

    - hasPart: SiteNavigationElement
  - mainEntity: ContactPage

    - contentLocation: Place

> ```html
>              @*...*@
>             </div>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </div>
>
> <div>
>      @* some other stuff*@
> </div>
>
>     <div class="myfooter" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
> ```

Like WPHeader, WPFooter is missing hasPart. The finished schema looks like this:

- WebPage

  - hasPart: WPHeader

    - hasPart: SiteNavigationElement
  - mainEntity: ContactPage

    - contentLocation: Place
  - hasPart: WPFooter

If you are able to change the layout page when inserting the contact page, the schema looks like this:

- ContactPage

  - hasPart: WPHeader

    - hasPart: SiteNavigationElement
  - contentLocation: Place
  - hasPart: WPFooter

The corrected code (including fixing `<nav></div>`) is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
    <meta property="og:title" content="test">
    <meta itemprop="about" content="test">
</head>
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <div class="myheader" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
        <div class="...">
             <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbarwrapper" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
                @*...*@
             </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    @RenderBody()

    <div>
         @* some other stuff*@
    </div>

        <div class="myfooter" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPFooter">
        @*...*@
        </div>
</body>
```

```html
<div class="banner">
    @* banner stuff *@
</div>
<div class="myMiddleContent" itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPage">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            @*...*@
            <div class="col-md-6" itemprop="contentLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                @*...*@
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Google Structured Data Testing Tool won't show this correctly as some items are missing content.

Comment: Thanks, guess schema.org needs more "real life" samples!

Comment: Is it still ok to add <html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebSite" to <html> tag to add itemprop="headline" etc... ?

Comment: @juFo Yes, but it may be preferable to use the headline property with WebPage depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I've made it possible now to change the WebPage type to ContactPage directly. Could you make an update to your original post of how this "should" look when doing everything correctly (might be interesting also for other users)?